# Create or Update Update a many-many relationship in Django Graphene

Tags: django, django-models

I had an issue of not being able to update Models with foreign keys in python django, below is my rating class

```
class Rating(Timestamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.movie} : {self.rating}'

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "movie"),)
```

I was trying to update it via the below mutation

```
class AddEditRating(graphene.Mutation):
    rating = graphene.Field(RatingType)

    class Arguments:
        movie = graphene.ID()
        user = graphene.ID()
        rating = graphene.Float()

    def mutate(self, info, **arg):
        user = arg.get("user")
        movie = arg.get("movie")
        rating = arg.get("rating")
        obj, created = models.Rating.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
            movie=movie,
            defaults={"rating": rating}
        )
        return AddEditRating(rating=obj)
```

When i hit the mutation thought I get a warning that the user must be of `UserType`

```
mutation {
  addEditRating(movie: 1, user: 3, rating: 9.7) {
    rating {
      id
      rating
    }
  }
}
```

Finally This is the error that i am getting

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot assign \"'3'\": \"Rating.user\" must be a \"User\" instance.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addEditRating"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Any help on this topic would be highly appreciated. also is there a better way to create update models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it

```py
obj, created = models.Rating.objects.update_or_create(
    user_id=user,
    movie_id=movie,
    defaults={"rating": rating}
)
```

Django will suffix the foreign key columns as name`_id`. If you use `user` or `movie` it expects it to be instances not ids.